# Mahout k-means clustering command : facing Heap Space Issues

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, heap-memory, k-means

I am trying to perform k-means clustering using mahout on a 300MB dataset containing only numerical values. But I am running out of memory in the k-means command after the second iteration. Why does the size increase after every iteration? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you may want to try using scikit-learn instead, as your data isn't really big

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use Mahout for small data sets. Just don't.**

300 MB easily fits into main memory of any modern computer. An in-memory implementation (maybe try [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/)) will **easily outperform Mahout**, because it does not have the overhead of Map Reduce.

Hadoop is not a one-size-fits-all solution. It is the super-size solution, and you don't have supersize data.

Any chance that you aren't even using a real cluster, but virtual machines? You might have too small diskspace or memory assigned, or your cluster is not well configured.

Comment: I am using the cluster itself, and the actual data size is quite large. my question is, is there any way to increase the heap space somehow? why does the size increase after every k-means iteration?

Comment: The mapper is supposed to use a constant amount of memory. It needs to store the cluster means and *one* data point. Where does your error *really* arise? Mapper? Shuffle? Reduce?